# Android BLE BluetoothGattCallback doesn't run

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

First, sorry for my english, second, I have a problem with a BluetoothGattCallback in Android studio for ble, the app runs, I go in research and connection and it's ok, but the method in the callback  never starts, my principal interest is rssi.

This is my gattcallback:

```
  private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback =
        new BluetoothGattCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "fin qui tutto ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                TextView Rssitext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
                Rssitext.setText("RSSI"+ "null");

                if (status == gatt.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,rssi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Rssitext.setText("RSSI"+ rssi);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"fail read rssi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Rssitext.setText("RSSI"+ "null");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
                                                int newState) {
                String intentAction;
                if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                    mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                    boolean rssiStatus = mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi();
                    broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected to GATT server." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                    intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                    mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Disconnected from GATT server.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                }
            }

            @Override
            // New services discovered
            public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"onServicesDiscovered received: " + status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

and now when I call, I use has for automatic connect to specific device when are found

```
  private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public  void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, device.getName() + " " + device.hashCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if ((device.hashCode() == 676210690)|| (device.hashCode() == -1001190065))
            {

                mBluetoothGatt= device.connectGatt(context, false, mGattCallback);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "sought after device found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi();

            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Why do you think that another device send something to you?

Comment: What do you mean with "I use has for automatic connect to specific device when are found"?